# Inherited class protobuf-net serialization

Tags: protobuf-net

After serialization of inherited class C2 stream looks like that:

0x5a
0x03

0x08
0x97
0x01

0x08
0x96
0x01

I can't understand that is the first group of bytes (5a 03)? I believed its must be second and third only which are representing Z1 and Z2 values?

My code:

```
    [ProtoContract]
    class C1
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
        public int Z1 { get; set; }
    }

    [ProtoContract]
    class C2 : C1
    {
        [ProtoMember(1, DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
        public int Z2 { get; set; }
    }      

    public static void Main()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(C1), true).AddSubType(11, typeof(C2));
        C2 c2 = new C2() {Z1 = 150, Z2 = 151};           
        Serializer.Serialize(stream, c2);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 0x5a = field-number 11, wire-type 2 (length prefixed) - this represents the inheritance via encapsulation of sub-classes as inner-messages
- 0x03 = 3 (length of payload)

  - 0x08 = field 1, wire-type 0 (varint)
  - 0x97 0x01 = 151 (varint = little-endian using MSB as continuation)
- 0x08 = field number 1, wire-type 0 (varint)

  - 0x96 0x01 = 150

which basically maps to (in .proto)

```
message C1 {
    optional int32 Z1 = 1;
    optional C2 c2 = 11;
}
message C2 {
    optional int32 Z2 = 1;
}
```

Comment: You wrote at another thread (if i remeber correctly) that inheritance is not part of protobuf specification. So why is serialization looking like that (with encapsulation in front of packet)? Any way to eliminate this, so it will be something like that: [code]message C1 {
    optional int32 Z1 = 1;
}
message C2 {
    optional int32 Z2 = 1;
}[/code]

Comment: @GromHellscream indeed, inheritance isn't part of the protobuf specification; protobuf-net offers an implementation for convenience, using encapsulation. The serialiation isn't "in front of" the packet - the entire things is a single protobuf message, usable from any platform. The "soemthing like that" you propose makes no sense: neither includes the other. The entire issue here is that when talking about inheritance, you need to be able to send *either* - so you could send **just** a `C1` (not the `C2` sub-class), or a new `C3` subclass of `C1` or `C2`. protobuf-net can handle that. If you...

Comment: @GromHellscream ...want to completely flatten your model (losing the substitution support), then that can be done too, but you'd basically end up with something like `message C2 { Z1 = 1; Z2 = 2; }` - you can do that pretty easily, but: then it doesn't really support inheritance by the usual meaning of the word.

Comment: In my case i don't need substitution support and inheritance data inside serialized packet because both ends (client and server) have all type hierarchy description on their sides. Actually, server side are embedded device and using pure c++ protobuf which dont support protobuf-net inheritance convention (yes, i can implement it, but it will be useless performance overhead). Type hierarchy represents domain-specific high-level entities, so using nested properties or one-level hierarchy classes are very inconvenient.

Comment: Why protobuf-net can't simply collect all properties marked with ProtoMember attribute from all base classes in case if i don't changed RuntimeTypeModel (or explicitly defined this behaviour)?

Comment: @GromHellscream well, for starters : because that would give it two definitions for field 1 in your example, which clearly doesn't work. But also: more commonly, inheritance models are intended to reflect the inheritance in the serialization so it can be reconstructed. That doesn't apply in your case. As it happens, the type model can be configured the way you want at runtime, but frankly I would propose it is more appropriate to model it as a DTO that represents how you want it to appear, i.e. without inheritance.

Comment: @MarcGrovell, of course field identifiers must be unique through all type hiearchy, this is not a problem.

Comment: i understand your vision of inheritance model. But it would be nice to have simple form of serializaton too. It will be usefull for many, i guess. And thanks for suggestion, i will look into it.

Comment: why after operation Serializer.NonGeneric.Deserialize(typeof(C2), stream), where C2 from OP except the line with ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel, stream position becomes 6 although it deserialized only 3 bytes?

Comment: @Grom why do you think it only deserialized 3 bytes? Also: do you mean 8 (not 6)?

Comment: i deserialized this stream: {0x10, 0x97, 0x01, 0x08, 0x96, 0x01} and found that protobuf-net readen 6 bytes instead of 3 (which a supposed to be i guess). Here my test: http://pastebin.com/QiSaAmBS

Comment: @Grom ah, right - I thought you still meant the data from the OP (since you mentioned the OP). Why do you think it should read only 3 bytes? The serialized data is all 6.

Comment: Because it ignores all base class parameters (which don't belong to RuntimeTypeModel) at serialization (so it will be 3 bytes in my example). Also during deserialization it reads 6 bytes but skips first 3, so they are lost forever. Also i suppose deserialization must be inverse operation for serialization which is don't work in your case.

Comment: @Grom without seeing **exactly** how you've configured RuntimeTypeModel, it is impossible to say much. But a protobuf stream always reads to the end, unless you pin the length. Do you have a complete example of your code here, so that I can comment?

Comment: I don't configured RuntimeTypeModel at all because i don't want to serialize inheritance itself (only data from all base classes). I'm already posted this link above http://pastebin.com/QiSaAmBS . Can't past code here.

Comment: @Grom hmm, more sure I saw the comment on the 14th; I'll have to look, but busy with family today